# Sorting bib entries in amsrefs

Tags: sorting, amsrefs

Is there any way to automatically sort the entries within a biblist environment? 
For example sort alphabetically by author names, type of entry, etc. .
Unfortunately I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. If you have time, you can consult our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize with the format.

Comment: Sorting of the bibliography is only available when using Bibtex and  an external bib file - see section 2.3 of the amsrefs documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Sections 2.2 and 2.3 of the [documentation of amsrefs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs) describe using `amsrefs` without and with BibTeX.  In section 2.2, without BibTeX it says:

> • No sorting of the bibliography items is done. The entries will
>   appear in your document in the same order that they appeared in the
>   database files.

In section 2.3 with BibTeX you will find:

> • you can take advantage of BibTEX’s ability to sort your items for you, ...

Thus out of the box, `amsrefs` without BibTeX will not sort bibliographies for you.

Comment: I believe that amsrefs is not support alphabetic sort, as stated in *section 6.15.5 Citation sorting* of [doc of amsrefs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs), there is a warning for non-numeric citation:`ifx\citesel\citesel@number
...
\else
\NonNumericCiteWarning
\process@citelist@unsorted{#1}
\fi`

Comment: @user19832 That code refers to sorting of citation lists, i.e. the elements in `\cite`, not the bibliography list itself.

Comment: yeap, I know, and I mean the alphabetic sort is not supported in `\citelist{\cite{B}\cite{A}}`, is there a way to sort it (use amsrefs)?

Comment: @user19832 Such sorting is not built in.  But if you ask a question on this site, there is a good chance that some will be able to provide some code to do that sorting.